# Does model need normalized data?

Tags: machine-learning, model, normalization, feature-scaling

With a very limited time to look at the model's architecture, how does one decide whether or not an arbitrary model need normalized input data?

There are tons of ML libraries out there and most of the time the end-user only has a vague idea about what the algorithm is doing on the inside.

---

For example, suppose I only the know the naive k-means algorithm *this* deep:

> Specify number of clusters K.
> Initialize centroids by first shuffling the dataset and then randomly selecting K data points for the centroids without replacement.
> Keep iterating until there is no change to the centroids. i.e assignment of data points to clusters isn’t changing.
> Compute the sum of the squared distance between data points and all centroids.
> Assign each data point to the closest cluster (centroid).
> Compute the centroids for the clusters by taking the average of the all data points that belong to each cluster.

[source](https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-clustering-algorithm-applications-evaluation-methods-and-drawbacks-aa03e644b48a)

---

Can I still say whether or not this algorithm needs whitened data with reasonable confidence? What about K-Means? DBSCAN? SVM?

Is there some general flag that makes a new user go *"aha! so it does need normalization!"* ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common ways to check whether or not the model needs whitened data is to actually run it and see the results.

However, sometimes that's not an option (at an interview, for example).

---

First off, the reality check: most algorithms **do** need whitening. So, if no other option is present, say that it does. You will be right most of the time.

Now, what about the small number of algorithms that don't need normalized data, what do they all have in common?

- These algorithms **do not** combine (by any mathematical operation) two distinct features. The best example here is Decision Trees (and Random Forests). At each leaf, the decision tree splits the dataset using only *one feature at a time*.
- Algorithms that themselves provide whitening, namely the Batch Normalization layers in Neural networks. These also don't benefit from pre-normalized data.
- Algorithms that assume that every feature is independent of others. Like naive Bayes classifier and it's derivatives.

Does this help?